# Is there a way to import a .json file into js instead of putting it directly in the code?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a very long bit of json that looks a bit like this:

```
{
  "section: [
   [stuff]
  ]
}
```

and I'm currently doing this to get it into my js code:

```
var obj = {

  // {All the stuff from above}
}
```

I want to put it into a json file that can be locally imported to a js script to work like something like this:

```
var obj = "path/file.json";
```

and have it work the same way

Comment: Where are you executing your javascript code? Do you use a build chain?

Comment: I'm just doing it all locally while learning html and js.

Comment: Then the answer is probably no. If you had a local webserver instead of using the `file://` url, you could make a `fetch()` request to load the json, although even then it won't be synchronously available as if you had just included the data within the code.

Comment: Or look into the [filesystem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) for this with fetch.

```js
const pathToJson = "./path/file.json";
fetch(pathToJson)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json.section);
  });
```

*Note: this only works with a server. If you are using the `file:///` protocol, please switch to a regular server, for example if you have Python installed you can run in your directory: `python3 -m http.server`.*

Another (non-ideal) alternative is to create another JavaScript file with your JSON. Inside it put something like:

```js
var obj = {
  "section": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you can link it in your HTML in a script tag **before** your running script:

```html
<script src="./json-data.js"></script>
<script src="./my-script.js"></script>
```

And in `my-script.js`:

```js
console.log(obj.section); // {...}
```

Comment: @mlghackerxX as I mentioned in my answer, this **will not work for `file:///` protocols**, which you are using. Setup a local webserver or use the second option.

Comment: ah sorry thanks for the help though

Comment: @mlghackerxX if you're using Chrome (or the new MSEdge) you can easily setup a local http server with [the extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en), or if using VSCode the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension will do.

Answer (score 0):

Using fetch with async will allow you to use it without callbacks.

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
async function loadJSON() {
  var file = await fetch("/path/to/file.json");
  var obj = await file.json();
  // use object like usual here
}
loadJSON();
```